# How to access thousands of images on demand without memory overflow

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have about 5,000 images downloaded from a database that all stand for some object in a catalog. 

The catalog is displayed in a ListView (*Telerik*) but I want the images to show up next to each listview item.

Obviously with so many images I am sure to run out of memory if I put them in memory which I will not even attempt.

**My question is:** *In what other way may I implement this functionality?*

The user has the ability to scroll through all items at will. I guess I could implement pages with in the list view and load on page change but lets leave that as a last resort.

**Environment:**
Win 7 64bit
Visual Studio 2010 pro
C#
Telerik WinForms

***EDIT 1***
I was asked to provide an image of how I want this to look like. This is a pretty good example. Just as this image mine will be able to change the view state to details view or icons view etc. Just like windows explorer.
You can find the image here: http://imgur.com/huEw4B6

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? just to give an idea of what you need. The image sizes, etc. If you can't post images here, try `imgur.com`

Comment: I just put a link to the image above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement paging, there is no other way. You can use:

- *Next*, *Previous*, *Page N* pattern. This works good with relational databases
- *Get more*. This works good with NoSQL databases where `Count` is a costly operation

From usability point of view, no one really needs 5000 items at once. This is why people invented search. From memory management, you can only store as much as your memory permits. Of course there are some tricks with swapping and memory paging, but this doesn't scale well.

If you are concerned with real-time search than it gets more complicated.

#### Common points

Any search works fast because the data is indexed, or in other words sorted. If data is sorted you can use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which is a `O(Log(N))` operation.

#### Client side search

If you have 5000 items, say cities as strings on a client side, then it's doable to cache that data locally, sort it once, and run quick search queries.

You can also invent a search on image tags and store images tags/description in memory.

This approach is limited to small data. When you hit the limit, there is no way to scale it and you must run a search query on the server

#### Server side search

When you cannot use client side filtering, do it on the server. This will vastly depend on your engine. A relational database would offer an indexed column, full-text search index and similar. A NoSQL database would offer indexes (as well), secondary indexes,  wide rows,  full text search fields and similar.

You can ask another question including the stack you using. I would advice to stop using client side search and look for scalable server side option, as it will work on 1 MB,  1 GB, 1 TB and even on 1PB scale (though with a lot more efforts).

Comment: What if I wanted a real-time search? Paging would make that more tedious. Telerik's ListView already supports real-time filtering on it's databound source but if the databound source does not hold all records at once then I can't search records that are not located on the current page no? If your case is the only way to go then I'm thinking about having two datasources? One holds all the 5,000 records with their respective members and is bound to the listview. The listview is then split into pages and on page changed event I download the images for the displayed items. This way the search

Comment: filters all items 5,000 items in real time. The image loading in the filtering, I imagine, would be clunky.

Comment: Hmm for my scenario it seems it would be more reasonable to mandate a search before displaying any results and then filter from there. My listview is supposed to offer multiple selections and that is the main reason why I wanted real time filtering so that it would appear "smooth" and "attractive". Guess i'll go plan B, server side searching. Thanks oleksii